# java.io.FileNotFoundException when reading a file

Tags: java, file

I am trying to read in a text file like this in Java (see code below).

Expected behavior when reading in the text file is:

1. When it finds `lesson`, it adds INF999, Java, 30 to Lesson object
2. When it finds `student`, it adds XXX name first 50 4 to Student object
3. When it finds `registration`, it adds XXX and INF999 to Registration object

Here's the code:

```
// test.txt
[lesson] INF999 Java 30
[student] XXX name first 50 4
[registration] XXX INF999

// readFile method
public void readFile(String path) {
   try {
      FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(path);

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
      String ligne;
      while ((ligne = br.readLine()) != null) {
          String[] words = ligne.split(" ");
          if (words[0].equals("[lesson]")) {
              String acronym = words[1];
              String name = words[2];
              int nbMaxStudents = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);
              addLesson(new Lesson(acronym, name, nbMaxStudents));
          } else if (words[0].equals("[student]")) {
              // same thing
          } else if (words[0].equals("[registration]")) {
              // same thing
          } else { throw new Exception(); }
      }
      br.close();
   } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("error"); }
}
```

In my `main` method I put this:

```
Programme programme = new Programme(numProgramme);
programme.readFile("test.txt");
```

I don't know why, but this execution always results in an error. Could you please help me?

Comment: instead of just printing "error", do e.printStackTrace(). That will tell you what's up.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt (No such file or directory). Isn't in the `src` ?

Comment: so the input file is not where you expect it

Comment: Input file is not there.Where have you put the file?

Comment: FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(new File(path)); May be problem is "chemin" is not having the path. Pass the path parameter.

Comment: If you are testing in Windows use D:/folder/filename.txt in Unix /path/filename.txt your code is working in my system with these changes. and remove  throw exception in else ** } else { throw new Exception(); }**

Comment: 1. I want a portable app so no absolute path 2. I get `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: With out absolute path also working in my system. You have to place the file in correct place. I placed the file in project folder it's working.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Programme programme = new Programme(numProgramme);
programme.readFile("src/test.txt");
```

Comment: I get `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: where have you used the 'path' variable.I cannot see that being used in the function

Comment: in the function? it's just in argument to get the file name

Comment: you should use it :  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));

Comment: I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt (No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the errors , you are mentioning ,There is no case handling for registration.. so it goes into the else block.

It is going in this line of code

```
else { throw new Exception(); }
```

and throwing exception for the registration i.e `when words[0].equals("[registration]")`

Comment: Oh sorry, my program is in french, i translate words for community. It's `registration`

Comment: okay then, Try to do like FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(path); Make sure you have your file there.

Comment: The problem is with the location of your test.txt file. When the program tries to search the txt file, it doesnt found it there and throws FileNotFoundException. Try to add the file directly under your project.